# I am trying to find a formula that will allow me to calculate MAX/MIN without calculating anything after the current row

Tags: excel, max, average, min

I want to use the Max/Min function to calculate the minimum number up to the current row, but not count anything after that row. See example below:

```
      A    B             C
1    10    =MIN(A1:A1)   I Want B1 to only count MIN from A1 to A1 from here, then 
2    14    =MIN(A1:A2)   from here I want B2 to count MIN from A1 to A2,
3     9    =MIN(A1:A3)   Then A1 to A3,
4     6    =MIN(A1:A4)   etc,
5    14    =MIN(A1:A5)   etc.
```

I could go back and update each row manually, but I have over 700 rows that I want all this to apply to. Is there anyone who can help me with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in B1, and copy downwards:

```
=MIN($A$1:$A1)
```

This is called maintaining referential integrity while writing any excel formula. It should give the desired result on copy towards right or downwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what copying right will do beyond repeating the original formula but downward should provide the correct results.

Comment: Since the column ($A) is constant, copying it right won't affect the result.